# Как добавлять контент во множество страниц

Tags: wordpress

Я (начинающий) написал себе (первый свой сайт) блог. (Уже готово) Но вот такая проблема: как добавить один контент во множество страниц. То есть, как реализовать, чтобы шапка сайта, футер и остальное остались неизменным, а менялся только контент. Я прочитал немного, нашел такой вариант как SSI (server side includes). Но он мне не очень понравился, я бы хотел использовать что-то посложнее.

Итак, возможно ли это реализовать с помощью движка WordPress или мне начинать учить pyhton.

Comment: В движке есть все, что нужно для работы с контентом. Так все-таки: один контент на множество страниц или везде разный? В вопросе: "один контент во множество страниц" и "а менялся только контент".

Comment: @KAGGDesign да вы правы вопрос был сформулирован неправильно. меняться    будет контент а шапка футер останутся неизменными.Так возможно с помощью  движка реализовать ?

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема? Много страниц? Контент надо генерировать программно? Куда его - на страницы сайта или в записи? Программно можно что угодно сделать. Опишите задачу подробнее.

Comment: @KAGGDesign к примеру возьмем my-hit.org как видите там постеры фильмов различных.А когда нажимаете на какую нибудь ссылку (фильма)основные блоки остаются неизменными типа  футера  и хедера остальное меняется на информацию о фильме которое вы выбрали.

Comment: Ну и что в этом примере? Самое банальное поведение сайта. Заполняйте свой контент (страницы или записи) руками, при переключении страниц шапка и подвал останутся неизменными.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как добавить один контент во множество страниц. То есть, как
>   реализовать, чтобы шапка сайта, футер и остальное остались неизменным,
>   а менялся только контент

Нужно сперва чётко определиться - "один контент во множество страниц" или всё же "менялся только контент".

В общем видно, что ВП даже не брался в руки.
Вот  вначале поставь ВП, заполни его контентом, а потом приходи с конкретным вопросами.

> Итак, возможно ли это реализовать с помощью движка WordPress или мне
>   начинать учить pyhton.

Pyhton (как и SSI) к WordPress никаким боком. Учить нужно WP и php.

Comment: да вы правы ВП не брался в руки )